# How to implement Windows 10 toast notification with input textbox in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-10, toast

This↓ is C# but I want to implement it in PowerShell.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts?tabs=builder-syntax#inputs

I didn't know how to write .. xml.

environment

- PowerShell 5
- Windows 10

expected↓

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<toast>
    <visual>
        <binding template="ToastGeneric">
            <text>$($title)</text>
            <text>$($message)</text>
            # <inputTextBox?>...
        </binding>
    </visual>
</toast>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can not  implement it in PowerShell...
the website you provided, show how to use it clear:

```
Install Notifications Visualizer. This free Windows app helps you design interactive toast notifications by providing an instant visual preview of your toast as you edit it, similar to Visual Studio's XAML editor/design view. See Notifications Visualizer for more information, or download Notifications Visualizer from the Store.
```

if you want build a app/notify-app you must learn how to use vs and c# but PowerShell